# Passing a delegate to the WPF WebBrowser.InvokeScript method

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, asynchronous, delegates

```
public void ProcessResult(string result)
{
   this.MyTextBox.Text = result;
}

...

this.WebBrowser.InvokeScript("jsFunctionName", ProcessResult);
```

I need to achieve something like this. The JavaScript function "jsFunctionName" is asynchronous and expects a callback which captures the result.

However, the second parameter of InvokeScript method accepts an array of Objects. So, how do I pass this C# method/delegate to the InvokeScript method?

**EDIT:**

Even if we can pass the delegate to the WebBrowser control, how will the script in the control invoke the C# delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at this article for details on two-way communication implementation with InvokeScript: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0746166.aspx

Also, objects passed are not callbacks but arguments. If you want to pass method, I'd go for passing method name with necessary prefix as string to the function.

Here's simple code that shows how the call is organized from js side (via button click, though it may be apprehended to be used as a simple call):

```
<button onclick=\"window.external.Test('called from script code')\>...</button>
```

If there are problems invoking any method from js, you're always free to implement generic function that takes string function name and calls the necessary function:

```
public void CallMethod(string methodName, params object[] parameters)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! Apart from this, I had to create an interface and make the [ComVisible(true)], and the interface contains methods that are accessible from JavaScript. Also, I set the [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)] for my Window class.

This way I could eliminate the NonComVisibleBaseClass error at runtime.